# jQuery - Catching a change on the validation status on a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input-field

I had a input field in my form that have the following class:

```
class="form-group field-sale-first_name required"
```

and after client side validation it can have one of two different classes added to it.

```
class="form-group field-sale-first_name required has-success"
```

or

```
class="form-group field-sale-first_name required has-error"
```

I'm trying to catch when this class has success of error status with jQuery method hasClass() but always getting True even when the .has-error or the has-success are not there.

```
<form id="checkout-form" action="/site/checkout" method="post">

    <div class="form-group field-sale-first_name required">
    <input type="text" id="sale-first_name" class="form-control" name="Sale[first_name]" placeholder="First Name">
```

and the script:

```
clientValidationStatus = (function() {
    if ($("form-group.field-sale-first_name.required").hasClass(".has-success)) {
      alert("Success");
    }
  })();
```

Could someone give a hint of how to get this change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us ur full html and js code for this

Comment: how are you trying it in jquery? Share your js.

Comment: added. that should be enough. The script i can call like this or on an onclick event, its not the point here.

Comment: Right now you have syntax error near `(".has-success)`. Moreover, `"form-group` has to be `".form-group`. Not to mention already voiced `"has-success"`.

Comment: .hasClass(".has-success) shouldn't have the . before has-success

Comment: hm, also: you've got a syntax error there

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Ahh those little mistakes... Sorry for the silly question. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing hasClass syntax `hasClass("has-success")` and for `form-group`

```
  clientValidationStatus = (function() {
        if ($(".form-group.field-sale-first_name.required").hasClass("has-success")) {
          alert("Success");
        }
      })();
```

Comment: added @Regent missed that bro was focusing on hasClass syntax.